# Как дописать строку NSLog?

Tags: objective-c, macos

Мне необходимо вывести одну строку двумя вызовами NSLog. Я думал что код:

```
int i = 0;
NSLog(@"Number ");
...
NSLog(@"%d", i);
```

Покажет:

> Number 0

Но он выводит:

> ```
> Number
> 0
> ```

NSLog вставляет новую строку автоматически. Как мне дописать первый вызов NSLog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это не правильно, используйте либо буфер либо [printf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3503721/887325) подобную функцию.

Comment: В вопросе требуется 2  вызова NSLog, а не один.

Answer (score 5):

Может так, или я не понял вопроса.

```
int i = 0;
NSLog(@"Number %d", i);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int i = 0;
printf("Number ");
printf("%d", i);
```